# smb printer works when opening printer spooler

Tags: networking, printing, samba

I have a Samsung 3200 in a windows machine connected over smb to my linux machine.

When I send something to print it doesn't do anything, so I open the printer spooler and as soon as it opens, I see the printing jobs in line change status to processing and begins to print normally.

Any ideas on what might be causing this issue?

If it might lead somewhere, this problem started to happen after I changed the IP from the windows machine and changed the target IP from the printer properties in ubuntu

Comment: Whenever you change IPs either for a standalone printer or a printer connected to a computer acting as a print server (your case), you should remove the old printer's configuration in the clients and add it again.